# How to Get all items from Form panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

How to get all items from the FormPanel in Extjs 5.0?

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#ownform')[0].query('.field').forEach(function(item){});
```

The code is working for textbox and combobox but my form contains grids and buttons etc.

Comment: `var everything = theForm.query('*');`

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, I guess this way you select ALL components, including those that are internal to the other components (like picker field for combo)? Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: If you want only the first level items of the form, there is a property on the form called `.items` which is a collection you can iterate over. You should get all items of the form using: `var formItems = theForm.items`. See doc: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-property-items

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is , try to get the Basic Form first myform.getForm() and then use getFields  method like example below .

```
        var form = this.up('form').getForm();

        form.getFields().each(function(item){
                item.setRawValue('test1');
        });
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/eb1oo94f/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "all items from the FormPanel" there are different answers for this question.

If you want all descendant items/Components:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#ownform component');
```

If you want all direct children items/Components:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#ownform > component');
```

Please see the [Ext JS 5.0 Ext.ComponentQuery doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/Ext.ComponentQuery.html) for more information on buidling component query selectors.